# NodeJS delete specific records when the date reaches 60 days

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Good evening. Im Using JSJoda to calculate the difference between two dates. In the database there is a row where by default, the date is inserted automatically.
I need to create a normal function (without Req, Res object) where each row will be deleted after 60 days.

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const JSJoda = require('js-joda');
const {deleteRecord, getAllMessages} = require('../connection/db.js');

exports.deleteMessage = async () => {
    /**
     *      Get all the messages and delete statement
    */
   const deleteStatement = 'DELETE FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?';
   const selectStatement = 'SELECT * FROM message';


    try 
    {
        const messageList = await getAllMessages(selectStatement);
        
        /**
         *      Loop over the array of messages and find the date
        */
        for (message of messageList) {
            let dateTarget = message.dateAdded;
            
        /**
         *      Convert the date to ISOString() and leave only the dates
         */
            let messageDates = dateTarget.toISOString().split('T')[0];
            let today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

            let difference = JSJoda.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(JSJoda.LocalDate.parse(messageDates), JSJoda.LocalDate.parse(today));
            
            while (difference === 0) {
                // Problem is here I dont know what should I do
                await deleteRecord(deleteStatement, 'message', message.messageID, value);
            }
        }
    } 
    
    catch (error) 
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

In this function I get all the records, and parsed it to the required format by the library. The variable bellow apparently shows the right days, But now I realised that I am stuck.

```
let difference = JSJoda.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(JSJoda.LocalDate.parse(messageDates), JSJoda.LocalDate.parse(today));
```

I dont know how should I proceed with this function.... Where to place it, and the most important, how to select the right `messageID` that must be deleted.

This is the actual columns from MySQL
[image]

Comment: Would a mySQL trigger be simpler? I think instead to solve an issue I created another...